# ios 9 Search Cancel undoes action

Tags: ios, swift, ios9

I have two buttons on top of a map. If you tap the search button the buttons animate to switch places; which is what i want. However if you cancel the search I would like the buttons to switch back. I tried this

```
self.searchDisplayController.active = false
```

(which i know is depreciated) 
inside of an if statement and it did not work
I was wondering what code I could put inside an if statement would do what I want to do.

Here is the search button code

```
@IBAction func showSearchBar(sender: AnyObject) {
    searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
    self.searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
    presentViewController(searchController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    setButtonPosition("buyer")



}
```

the last line

```
 setButtonPosition("buyer")
```

is what switches the button position

Thanks